# Error in query while performing insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this is my code and for which i m getting error query mssg:

```
 $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fname']));
 $emailid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['emailid']));
 $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['city']));
 $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comment']));
 $query="INSERT INTO userdate('name','city','emailid','pledge','date') VALUES       ('$name','$city','$emailid','$comment',NOW())";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('error query');
```

Comment: And what's the error message you're seeing? 
What's the datatype of emailid?

Comment: @p.campbell datatype is varchar and the msg is error query i.e. one that runs query.

Comment: I've seen this exact same problem in another question by a different user. Some lecturer isn't doing their job

Comment: (`'@name'`,.../etc doesn't perform string concatenation, as I understand, in PHP

Comment: @OMG Ponies - They do have the whole string within double quotes though. That will do the concatenation.

Comment: @ashish Don't be ambiguous when posting error messages. It will be something like *"You have an error in your SQL query near..."*. Please post the error as reported

Comment: @Buggabill `s/concatenation/interpolation`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have single quotes and not backticks in your query.

```
$query="INSERT INTO userdate('name','city','emailid','pledge','date') VALUES ('$name','$city','$emailid','$comment',NOW())";
```

Should be:

```
$query="INSERT INTO userdate(`name`,`city`,`emailid`,`pledge`,`date`) VALUES ('$name','$city','$emailid','$comment',NOW())";
```

Comment: Backticks are only necessary if the column names are MySQL reserved words: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @ashish - No. They are not okay around the field names.  OMG Ponies is right, the backticks are not required, but if you insist on having something around your field names (not your values) then, you need to use backticks.